# CFBundleDocumentTypes key must be an array of dictionaries when I validate my app

Tags: ios, xcode

I get the following error when I try to Validate my app to the App Store as follows:

This bundle is invalid. The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at least the CFBundleTypeName key.

Heres my code:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>inCommand icon114</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>xxx</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.xxxxxxxx.quizMaker.xxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict/>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally had this as a comment, but pretty sure this is what's wrong.

The second last line `<dict/>` is an empty dictionary which does not contain the key `CFBundleTypeName` mentioned by the error.

Remove it and you should be OK!

Comment: yep .. that solved the problem. Thank you very much